# Excel incremental formula on filtered data

Tags: excel

So I want to have referencing formulas that are incremental in an excel column,

e.g. in B1 (filtered data) I want to put:

```
=Sheet1!F6
```

The next row in filtered data (under B1) is maybe B4, but I want to put in there

```
=Sheet1!F7
```

so the reference to Sheet 1 Column F is going up by 1 each time but only on data that is present once filtered in the B column.

Comment: Slightly-related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217023/conditional-formatting-on-visible-range/41230047#41230047

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at the post in Tim Williams' comment.

Imaging your data that is filtered is in col A. in Col B fill 1 and use the below formula in column c

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!F" & (5+SUBTOTAL(9,B$2:B2)))
```

[image: Excel Screenshot]

After Filter

[image: Excel Screenshot after filter]